# Django/coreapi how to use a local swagger file?

Tags: django, swagger

Probably a very simple matter, but I have not been able to find an answer...
The short story is this: I have to develop an API client on top of a Django site we have. I think Coreapi would be the way to go.

However, the documentation for it says that you should initialize the client as:

```
schema = client.get('https://api.example.org/')
```

Which implies that every time before I do an API call I need to download the full swagger file from the remote site?

Given that a) we are going to be doing MANY calls, and b) the other site (which runs the server API to which my app is the client) will not be changing that API any time soon (and, if it does, we will need to re-do most of our code anyway), can't I just download the swagger locally and then initialize using the local copy?